# FFMPEG zoompan only applies and shows 3 images out of the many

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, ffmpeg-php

I am trying to generate a video from images using FFMPEG 4.0 windows built on AWS windows instance using PHP.

```
$command2="ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i https://<path>/$images%d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 5  -t $total_video_time -y  ".trim($video_name)." -i http://<path>/$audio ";
```

The above generates the correct video output with all the input images (50 in this case) but without the zoompan effect on the images.

Now I try to add the zoompan effect for the images using -

```
$command2="ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i https://<path>/$images%d.jpg  -filter_complex zoompan=z='zoom+0.002':d=25*4:s=1280x800 -pix_fmt yuv420p  -c:v libx264 -r 5  -t $total_video_time -y  ".trim($video_name)." -i http://<path>/$audio ";
```

This will only pick up the first 3 images and apply the zoompan to the first two images or so.

Can you please help me with this issue? Any inputs, pointers are welcome too.

Comment: How do you calculate `$total_video_time`?

Comment: Number of images * 5 (so per image for 5 sec)

Comment: This works here : `ffmpeg -i images -i audio -vf zoompan=z='zoom+0.002':d=25*5:s=1280x800 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -t total time out.mp4`. For zoompan effect, you don't want a low framerate output.

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect! Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it below?

Comment: Low framerate for the output was the issue indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zoompan filter defaults to 25 fps output, but your output rate was causing most frames to be dropped. Input rate is irrelevant when zoompan is filtering the images.

```
ffmpeg -i images -i audio -vf zoompan=z='zoom+0.002':d=25*5:s=1280x800 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -t total time out.mp4
```